# Using Vue.js to bind value of input field to a second input field

Tags: symfony, vue.js

I have Symfony Form which defined as below (minus non-pertinent fields for brevity):

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Form;

use AppBundle\Entity\Category;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class CategoryType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('label', TextType::class, [
                'label' => 'label.display_name',
                'attr' => [
                    'placeholder' => 'placeholder.category_name',
                    'class' => 'label',
                    '@input' => 'vUpdateSlug'
                ]
            ])
            ->add('slug', TextType::class, [
                'label' => 'label.slug',
                'attr' => [
                    'class' => 'slug',
                    '@input' => 'vUpdateSlug',
                    ':value' => 'slug'
                ]
            ]);
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => Category::class,
            'category_id' => null
        ]);
    }
}
```

I am attaching Vue.js directives to both `input` fields.  The idea is that when someone types in the `label` field, the `slug` field is automatically updated with the `label` `input` value with some minor changes (replacing spaces with hyphens). I still want the user to be able to alter the slug if they wish, but not have the label update.

The `v-on:input/@input` directive behaviour works, however, I'm just starting with Vue.js and my implementation feels a little clunky (repetitive) - see below:

```
new Vue({
    delimiters: ['[[', ']]'],
    el: '#category-form',
    data: {
        slug: this.slug = $('[name="category[slug]"]').val()
    },
    ready: function () {
        this.slug = $('[name="category[slug]"]').val();
    },
    methods: {
        vUpdateSlug: function (event) {
            var str = event.target.value.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9 -]/g, '').replace(/\s+/g, '-').toLowerCase();
            return this.slug = str;
        }
    }
});
```

Is there a better solution to my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After more researching and tinkering, I came up with the following which produces the desired result:

**CategoryType**

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('label', TextType::class, [
            'label' => 'label.display_name',
            'attr' => [
                'placeholder' => 'placeholder.category_name',
                'class' => 'label',
                'v-model' => 'label'
            ]
        ])
        ->add('slug', TextType::class, [
            'label' => 'label.slug',
            'attr' => [
                'class' => 'slug',
                '@input' => 'setSlug',
                ':value' => 'slug'
            ]
        ]);
}
```

**Vue Script**

```
new Vue({
    delimiters: ['[[', ']]'],
    el: '#form-wrapper',
    data: {
        label: $('[name="category[label]"]').val(),
        slug: $('[name="category[slug]"]').val()
    },
    watch: {
        label: function(newLabel) {
            this.slug = this.compileSlug(newLabel)
        }
    },
    methods: {
        compileSlug: function(input) {
            return input.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9 -]/g, '')
                .replace(/\s+/g, '-')
                .toLowerCase();
        },
        setSlug: function (input) {
            this.slug = this.compileSlug(input.target.value)
        }
    }
});
```

[JSFiddle functioning example](https://jsfiddle.net/Veleous/vvqgxdb2/1/)